# Particles fail to show in final render

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

I have a cube emitter which emits simple blue particles. They appear in the 3D View, but not in final render. I have followed [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Particle_Systems) tutorial (but not with plane) and my file is [here](http://pasteall.org/blend/39874).

Thanks for an answer!

Comment: Your question can be made clearer by you.  Please show an image of the 3D View and Render.  Give us visual clues please.

Comment: the file that you provide works as intended... the particles are rendered just fine. They are small though... You can either increase the size, or instance an object at each particle. Make you sure you have latest version of blender 2.76b right now)

Comment: Particles [indeed work](http://imgur.com/oh3UGRF), and can be rendered as expected. One option to make them more visible is to increase the size of glow in the material settings (**Material** > **Halo**)..

Answer (score 1):

I have figured it out, the particles don't show in simple render, unless they're activated in scene before. If they are, the render show them statically at their place. If I want them to move in render, I need to use animated render (ctrl+F12).

Thank you all for your attention!